# Accessing /home/user data from an Ubuntu system mounted as external drive on Debian wheezy

Tags: ubuntu, mount, debian

I just switched my Hard Drives and I would like to copy my data from the old HDD to the new HDD.

I have mounted the old HDD at `/mnt`, it is a LVM Ubuntu partition. What I would like to do is copy my old user directory  which should be located under under `/mnt/home/user1`. The `dir` however seems to be protected or unaccessible, I can't remember if I have encrypted the data or not.

In my file manager I get a lock symbol and when I open the dir it is empty! **Update:** I have opened it with root rights, the lock disapears but the directory stays empty.

Further the username and pwd were the same on the old and the new system if that helps.

Is there a way to access the data on the mounted external LVM drive without switching the HDDs back and copy all data to a third drive first?

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107859968 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773164 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b2653

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2          501758   976771071   488134657    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5          501760   976771071   488134656   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: 491.6 GB, 491635343360 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 59771 cylinders, total 960225280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: 8162 MB, 8162115584 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 992 cylinders, total 15941632 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

And mount of the partition as requested:

```
mount
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root on /mnt type ext4 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

Comment: What does "seems to be protected or unaccessible mean"? Please post any errors etc.

Comment: In my file manager I get a lock symbol and when I open the dir it is empty!

Comment: Can you add the output of `mount` and `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: Also check whether there aren't any errors in the system log (output of `dmesg` and files `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` or their appropriate equivalent on your system).

Comment: Why is this put on hold? What is not clear about the question?

Comment: ok looks like the home directory of the ubuntu HDD was encrypted. So I switched HDDs again and copied from ubuntu to the mounted debian HDD. All is well!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the uid of the home directories does not match the uid on the new installation, and if the permissions of the directory are not `o+rx`, you may not be able to read the directory as a regular user.  Try browsing the mounted drive as root.